# Smarter way to detect input value changes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a smart - meaning the most flexible and stable way - to detect value changes in input fields via jQuery.

So far I came up with this which already fits my needs. But I wonder if there are some caveats to this method. Am I missing something?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // wait till page is loaded
  $('form :input').on("input", function() { // listen on all input fields on all forms
    form_name = $(this).parents("form").attr("name"); // gives id of form
    form_id = $(this).parents("form").attr("id"); // gives name of form
    input_name = this.name; // gives name of input field
    input_id = this.id; // gives id of input field
    input_value = this.value; // gives value of input field
    if (form_name == 'whatever' &&
      input_name == 'email' &&
      input_value == 'dummy@domain.com') alert('ok'); // do whatever you want
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you did the right thing by using the "input" event. That should be quite stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all input in your form by below code

```
  $('form :input').each(function () {
        $(this).on("change", function () {

           //your code

        });
    });
```

Comment: hardly any difference, but input has the edge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event